# Show image of $\Phi_a(t)=(e^{it}, e^{iat})$ is a submanifold of $S^1\times S^1$ iff $a$ is rational

Tags: manifolds, submanifold

Show the image of the map $\Phi_a(t): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ defined by $\Phi_a(t)=(e^{it}, e^{iat})$ is a regular submanifold of $S^1\times S^1$ if and only if $a$ is rational. I managed to show the implication from right to left but I'm not sure how to proceed to prove the other one.

I know that if $\Phi_a(\mathbb{R})$ is a regular submanifold of $S^1\times S^1$ then the inclusion map must be an embedding, i.e. it is an homeomorphism in its image and it is an imersion. I guess that being a homeomorphism doesn't tell me anything about what $a$ should be, so the answer must lie in the "imersion" part, but I don't know how to go on.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Some point whence $(1,1)$ is an accumulation point of $\Phi_a(2\pi \Bbb{Z})$. If $a$ is not rational then $\Phi_a(2\pi \Bbb{Z})$ is dense in $1\times S^1$. In that case the closure of $\Phi_a(\Bbb{R})$ is the whole of $S^1\times S^1$. But $\Phi_a(\Bbb{R})$ is not the whole of $S^1\times S^1$ so it is not a submanifold.

Comment: On the other hand if $a$ is rational then your map is periodic and therefore it can be seen as an injective map from $\mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$. It is easy to see that it is an immersion, so now you use that an injective immersion defined on a compact manifold is an embedding and therefore its image is a submanifold

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I'm going to try to write the details and then I'll post the answer.